# Can't send email with Sails.js and node-machine mailgun

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sails.js, mailgun

I've created with sails an API called JoinUs. What I want is to send an email before/after the new register is created. (**joinus/create** with the blueprint)

I'm using the node-machine code to send emails with mailgun. However, when I write this code in the JoinUs Controller (action create) it seems that is not working. I have the correct credentials of mailgun.

Any idea?

```
/**
 * JoinUsController
 *
 * @description :: Server-side logic for managing joinuses
 * @help        :: See http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Controllers
 */

module.exports = {

    create: function (res, req){
        var Mailgun = require('machinepack-mailgun');

        // Send an html email.
        Mailgun.sendHtmlEmail({
            apiKey: 'key-Xxxxxxxxxxxx',
            domain: 'domain.com',
            toEmail: 'dev@gmail.com',
            toName: 'DEV',
            subject: 'Welcome!',
            textMessage: 'Jane,\nThanks for joining our community. If you have any questions, please don\'t hesitate to send them our way. Feel free to reply to this email directly.\n\nSincerely,\nThe Management',
            htmlMessage: 'Jane,\nThanks for joining our community. If you have any questions, please don\'t hesitate to send them our way. Feel free to reply to this email directly.\n\nSincerely,\nThe Management',
            fromEmail: 'harold@example.enterprise',
            fromName: 'Harold Greaseworthy',
            }).exec({
            // An unexpected error occurred.
            error: function (err){

            },
            // OK.
            success: function (){

            },
        });    

    }
};
```

Comment: Now this code sends the email but it's not creating the record in the database. :(

Answer (score 1):

Look at this @DevArtisan [Sails Email Service](https://github.com/jasalazar/sails-email-service)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

I'm able to send the email but in doesn't create the record in the database. What I did is to rewrite the create controller as the code above and I don't know if that affects. Or how can I send the email at the moment I create the record I the database.